# Store a JSON data in a temp File, and delete after 24 hours?

Tags: php, json, apache

How can I store JSON Data temporary on my Apache Server. In the JSON are some user information. It would be really nice if the files would delete every 24 hours themselves.

```
$json_array = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
 $json_array[] = $row; 
 } 

 $final_array = json_encode($json_array);
```

So like this I create the JSON File, and I could also Store this in a .json File but how can i create temp Files with this data in it. And this File should only be readable from the server.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you can share the code which you tried, then the community can help.

Comment: To write to file you can use fwrite. For deleting, you can use cron-tab to clear the file's content every 24h

Comment: I edit the code

Comment: Your code doesn't create any file, it just store the JSON into a variable.

Comment: @catcon Yeah I know I just want to show how I create the JSON data.

Comment: is this JSON file per user?

Comment: @niklaz yeah, every user have other data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file_put_contents` to store data, but create some prefix for each user, so you can have separate files, and retrieve them after:

```
 $json_array = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
 $json_array[] = $row; 
 } 

 $final_array = json_encode($json_array);
 $generatedName = 'userIDprefix_userData' .  '.json'; //replace userIDprefix with user ID, this way we can use prefix to store different files per user, and retrieve file for user
 //use file put contents to store data 
 file_put_contents('path/to/json/data/' . $generatedName , $final_array);
```

Use `file_get_contents()` to retrieve file data:

```
 $generatedName = 'userIDprefix_userData' .  '.json'; //replace userIDprefix with user ID, this way we can use prefix to store different files per user, and retrieve file for user
 //use file put contents to store data 
 $userJSONData = file_get_contents('path/to/json/data/' . $generatedName );
```

And then setup the cron to run say each 5 minutes,  use `glob` and `filemtime` to scan the dir where you store data and `filemtime` to get timestamp of file, to compare with current date and delete if it is older than 24h

```
$past24hours = strtotime('-24 hours');
foreach (glob("path/to/json/data/*.json") as $filename) {
   if( filemtime($filename) < $past24hours ){
     unlink($filename);
    }
}
```

Setup cron to execute the file where the script for json files deletion is to be run say, every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/to/delete-json.php
```

**Note:**

Do not set permissions to 777 to this folder, at least 775, or even 755. 
Also, to prevent from accessing .json files directly, put in this folder at least blank index.php, and .htaccess with content:

```
#forbid access to folders and to files  
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule \.(json|txt)$ - [F] 
 deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it right that I have to change the folder permissions on the Data folder to 777?

Comment: @User9123, not unless you want them accessible publicly and they are stored in publicly accessible path. Otherwise, folder should be set at least to 775, or even 755, so that way only owner, and/or group has all permissions, and other ( world ) will have only read and execute

Comment: Problem is I have no Security on this Data Folder. So everbody who knows the File name can read the .json. Any suggestion?

Comment: @User9123, add blank index.php, and .htaccess within that directory with directive as mentioned in my edited answer at the bottom.

Comment: I think I have to activate .htaccess because I never worked with it. And Im not sure with the permissions. If I take 777 everthing works but with 775 or 755 I get some errors

Comment: And its creating two Files at one Login but otherwise everthing works

Answer (score 0):

Why did you think this much ?
why not trying php session or cookie for 24hrs or browser js localStorage ?

if need Temp file ,create file in Apache server using php-Apache file creation and writing methods after 24hrs delete that file using [Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325350/setting-cron-job-to-delete-file-after-24-hours)

Comment: Thx for ur answer.